# Ajax and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, get

Ok so I have this query in my controlller

```
    @number1 = 3
    @number2 = 6
    @itemsok = Contribution.where("first_item_id = ?",@number1).where("first_item_grade = ?",@number2)
```

I have also 2 variables wich should make the query "custom"(not right now)... The question is, how can I save a user input into that variables so it can be "dynamic"...

I think that one approach is to create fom with a button like this:

```
<%= button_to 'All perfect', contribution_path(:id=> contribution.number1),
                    :remote => true %>
```

But how do I listen for this event in Rails?

I am completely lost. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand your question you would like the user to be able to enter in values to a form that are then used in the controller to perform a search on the data in your database?

If so you should start with a form in your view, something like:

```
<%= form_tag(contribution_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "Number 1:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:number1) %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "Number 2:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:number2) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

If your routes are set up correctly this will then send the parameters to your controller so you can use them like so:

```
@number1 = params[:number1]
@number2 = params[:number2]
@itemsok = Contribution.where(:first_item_id => @number1).where(:first_item_grade => @number2)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need, but just as you said my routes are not correct, I got an error like this: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"contributions"}      I think I have to configure my routes to "get method" ??

Comment: I'm not sure what your controller name or action name is but it should probably look something like this:
get 'contribution' => 'contribution#search', :as => 'contribution'

Where 'contribution' is your controller name and 'search' is your action name.

Double check with 'rake routes'

Comment: I just updated the post with my controller, I cant get it to work... Any other thoughts?

Comment: As ootoovak said, type rake routes to see what routes are configured.  Then look at the button to see what path it's set to go to.  You should be able to figure out the mismatch from that.